# How to pass access_token using POST GET

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a secret key (access token) which I need to pass to the server to authenticate. Not sure how to do this properly in python3. Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
mytoken='abcdefg123456'

headers='{ not sure what to put here!}

auth = requests.post(url='https://api.bitoasis.net/v1/access_token', headers=headers)
```

I need help on two things please... what to put in the headers and do I need to include data=mytoken after the url?

Comment: oauth access token header key is called bearer most of the time.. Besides that website is missing public online api documentation so no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Besides dont double post questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220480/unable-to-authenticate-credentials-python3